# Laravel Helpers Interface

Tags: php, laravel, interface

Simple example, I have the following helpers interface for calculations:

```
interface Calculation
{
    public function calculate();
}
```

And a few classes that implement this interface:

```
class One implements Calculation
{
    public function calculate()
    {
        return some calculation;
    }
}


class Two implements Calculation
{
    public function calculate()
    {
        return some different calculation;
    }
}

// and so on..
```

Now, in my view I have the code that I displayed below, but I want to be able to get rid of the if's here. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
foreach($units as $unit)
{
        $total = (new \App\Helpers\{$unit})->calculate();
}
```

How would I go about this?

```
foreach($units as $unit)
{
    if($unit === 'One')
    {
        $total = (new \App\Helpers\One)->calculate();
    }

    if($unit === 'Two')
    {
        $total = (new \App\Helpers\Two)->calculate();
    }

    if($unit === 'Three')
    {
        $total = (new \App\Helpers\Three)->calculate();
    }

    if($unit === 'Four')
    {
        $total = (new \App\Helpers\Four)->calculate();
    }

    // and so on..
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
   foreach($units as $unit)
    {
     $class="\\App\\Helpers\\".$unit;
     $total=(new $class)->calculate();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that's it, although I believe my interface is totally useless for what I am using it for at this moment, I still am learning about them so, thanks for this answer :)